# Istio egress not on AWS and Amazon RDS Aurora

Tags: amazon-rds, kubernetes

Has anyone been able to allow agrees from k8s pods using Istio as a service mesh without any kind of vpc peering?

From the docs you need an IP address range, however rds uses dns for endpoints.

How would you allow non https egress ?

Comment: Any success in this, facing a similar issue?